# Almost Sure Convergence to a Constant

Tags: convergence-divergence, stochastic-processes

General question - if I want to show that a sequence of random variables $(X_n)_{n \ge 1}$ converge almost surely to a constant, is it sufficient to show that $\lim_{n \to \infty}$Var$(X_n) = 0$? If not, under what conditions would this be sufficient?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: check the Monotone convergence theorem and Dominated convergence theorem.

Answer (score 0):

No.  For example $X_n$ sequence could consist of a sequence of random constants, i.e. all variances are $0$, but $X_n$ does not converge to anything.

As a minimum, you need to assume the sequence converges to something.

Answer (score 0):

Not only. For example, on a probability triple you have $X(\omega)=1 \ \forall \omega$ and
$$
X_n = \left\{
\begin{array}{lr}
1349 & \text{ if } \omega=0,\\
(1980)^n & \text{ if } \omega \in \big(0, \frac{2}{n}\big],\\
1-\frac{1}{n} & \text{ if } \omega \in \big(\frac{2}{n},1\big]
\end{array}\right.
$$
Then $X_n (\omega) \to_n X(\omega)$ a.a. If we remove $X_n(\omega)=1349$, it will converge everywhere, because it will include sets with Lebesgue measure $0$.